# Как создать такой массив на jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Хочу создать такой массив (копировал из console.log):

```
{name: "Виктор", years: 23, city: "Москва", amt_photo: "10", avatar: "111_11"}
```

пробовал через **new Map**, но получается совсем не то. Нужно чтобы в console.log было точно так как на примере.

Буду благодарен за помощь!

Comment: `console.log('{name: "Виктор", years: 23, city: "Москва", amt_photo: "10", avatar: "111_11"}')` исходя с инфы в вопросе, вам подойдет такой вариант :)
если нет расширте вопрос. ПС: ето обьект а не масив.

Comment: Никак, так как это не массив

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если правильно понял вопрос

```js
const array = Object.entries({name: "Виктор", years: 23, city: "Москва", amt_photo: "10", avatar: "111_11"});
console.log(array);
```